# C++ List Iterators Incompatible

Tags: c++, list

This is the code that I have in my main.cpp

```
std::list<AbstractBlock*>::iterator i;

    for (i = universe.getLoadedBlocks().begin(); i != universe.getLoadedBlocks().end(); i++){
        window.draw((*i)->draw());

    }
```

Universe.cpp:

```
std::list<AbstractBlock*> Universe::getLoadedBlocks(){
    return chunkManager->getLoadedBlocks();
}
```

CunkManager.cpp:

```
std::list<AbstractBlock*> ChunkManager::getLoadedBlocks(){
    return loadedBlocks;
}
```

And loadedBlocks is an `std::list<AbstractBlock*>`

I'm experimenting with lists and trying them out for the first time... I'm not sure why I'm getting this error

Comment: You should always use the preincrement operator on iterators (i.e. `++i`, not `i++`)

Comment: @pcluddite wouldn't that make it skip the first object in the list?

Comment: @pcluddite Care to share why the preincrement operator? I've never heard that before and it's not obvious to me.

Comment: @MagusCaligo No. The `for` loop executes `++i` after the entire block is run.

Comment: @JTrana The pre-increment operator does not return a copy (i.e., it may be more efficient for non-primitive types).

Comment: @JTrana Because `i++` evaluates the expression `i`, and then copies its next value into `i`.

Comment: Thanks @JamesAdkison, pcluddite- I will have to remember that!

Comment: @pcluddite The difference in the increment operator is not why the code has an error. It's the `getLoadedBlocks` return type that causes the issue.

Comment: @JamesAdkison Ah, my bad. I didn't read your answer or the question carefully enough.

Answer (score 10):

`std::list<AbstractBlock*> Universe::getLoadedBlocks() { ... }`
`^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ // This returns a copy of the list`

Therefore, `universe.getLoadedBlocks().begin()` uses one copy of the list and `universe.getLoadedBlocks().end()` uses a different copy of the list. This is why the iterators are incompatible (i.e., they are from different lists).

Said another way, the `begin` iterator of one list instance will never be equal to the `end` iterator from a different list instance.

If you don't change the `getLoadedBlocks()` function you could try:

```
std::list<AbstractBlock*> values = universe.getLoadedBlocks();
for (i = values.begin(); i != values.end(); i++) // Note: You should use ++i here (for possible efficiency benefits)
{
    window.draw((*i)->draw());
}
```

#### Edit

As [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42) points out you could also use the more convenient/succinct range-based for loop, assuming you're using a C++11 compatible compiler.

```
for (auto& block : universe.getLoadedBlocks())
{
    window.draw(block->draw());
}
```

Comment: Or, since C++11: `for (const auto* block : universe.getLoadedBlocks()) {
        window.draw(block->draw());
    }`